# How to access PreviousPage property in NavigatedToEventArgs in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to determine which was the previous page for current page in **.NET MAUI** application.

For example, there are 3 pages Page1, Page2, Page3

When going from Page1 to Page2, in Page2, I would like to access PreviousPage property which gives me "Page1" as value.

When going from Page3 to Page2, in Page2, PreviousPage property gives me "Page3" as value.

^^
However, I can only see "PreviousPage" property member in Debug mode when VS hits breakpoint. I cannot access it in code. Intellisense does not show this too.

How can I access and use this "PreviousPage" in my code? Is there any other way?

See screenshot.

[image]

I am using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.5.0 Preview 1.0

Thank you.

Comment: It's a non-public member you cannot access it, You do have access to the navigation stack though

Comment: Thanks. But if I come to Page2 from Page3, the NavigationStack does not show Page3. So there is no way of knowing if Page2 was reached using Page3 or Page 'n'.

Comment: What do you need that information for in the first place? You could store a reference somewhere yourself. However, be aware that the navigation stack can have a lot of items, technically. Would you always want to know which page was visible before the current one? That could become tricky very quickly, you would need some sort of navigation history.

Comment: I just need to know if the current page is visited first time or is it visited again (when user comes back to it). I want to load my CollectionView only once when page is visited first time. When coming back to the page, the "data" is already there in the page. I ask this since in UWP, we can always use "if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)" ; so thought MAUI would have something like this.

Comment: Accessing the previous page is not the ideal way to achieve this. You should rethink your code design here. How are you loading the content of your page? You should show the code for that, please add it to the question. Your actual question isn't "how to access the `PreviousPage` property?", but rather "how to load data of a page only once when the page is shown for the first time?", if I understood correctly.

Comment: Check to see if data is null or empty before loading it.  Or use a bool flag to track if the data has already been loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @[h-a-h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6643940/h-a-h) mentioned, custom logic was the way.
I implemented sort of workaround to make it work. I used navigation parameters.

My viewmodel constructor has attribute like this:

```
[QueryProperty("IsBack", "IsBack")]
public class Page2ViewModel
{
 //called from code-behind on OnNavigatedTo event using associated Command.Execute
 async Task LoadData()
 {
  if(IsBack == false) 
  {
   await _repos.GetListAsync();
  }
 }

 public bool IsBack {get;set;}
}
```

When going from Page1 to Page2, I do:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(View.Page2)}?IsBack={false}");
```

When going back to Page2 from Page3, I do:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..?IsBack={true}");
```

At least this way I know "when" Page2 is visited so as to prevent loading of data again. Though this does not let me know if I am coming back to Page2 from Page3 or Page'n', it solves my current requirement.

One can always use query parameters to provide the parent page.
e.g., from Page5 to Page2, we can do:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..?IsBack={true}&ParentPageId={nameof(View.Page5)}");
```

provided Page2's ViewModel has this QueryParameter attribute.

```
[QueryProperty("ParentPageId", "ParentPageId")]
```

Not very elegant but workable.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0

> Navigation events
> The Shell class defines the Navigating event, which is fired when navigation is about to be performed, either due to programmatic navigation or user interaction. The ShellNavigatingEventArgs object that accompanies the Navigating event provides the following properties...

Technically you can implement your own custom logic, to see if something has been loaded, what was source, the navigation paths, etc...

Your requirement can be achieved with minimum amount of code.

However, I do not think that navigation stack is a healthy way to check if something is displayed on your page or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the page in Navigation Stack, simply used:

```
var stack = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack;
int count = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count;
```

The current page is the last one, names (count - 1) index (as it is zero-based index) in the stack, so the previous page is  (count - 2) index.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried this. But when coming back to Page2 from Page3, the Page3 is no longer there in NavigationStack.